# Can I use both Django and Rest Framework views in a single project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to add some REST API views to an existing Django project, which uses vanilla [Django views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/). For that I'd like to use the [REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). I wonder if I can I mix Django and RF views in a single project and what pitfalls this might have (e.g. with authentication).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can surely use both of them at the same time, there shouldn't be any issue. Typically the Django views use SessionAuthentication, adn you will use DRF using TokenAuthentication -- best practice is to add both Session and Token authentication to the authentication_classes in the DRF views - that way you can use the browsable api pages to browse the apis once you have signed in via password (session authentication) as well

```
class GenericViewTest(SuperuserRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        return HttpResponse("Test")


class PostTrackingCode(CreateAPIView):
    """
    """
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)  ----> note this
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TrackingInfoWriteSerializer
    model = TrackingInfo
```